# Lossless conversion from wav 24bits to flac

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, conversion, flac, wav

Is it possible to have a lossless conversion from a wav file
`Stream #0:0: Audio: pcm_s24le ([1][0][0][0] / 0x0001), 48000 Hz, 1 channels, s32, 1152 kb/s` to a wav file ?

I tried using ffmpeg :
`ffmpeg -y -i KEEP_01.wav -acodec flac output.flac`
but i get this warning :
`Conversion will not be lossless.
Incompatible sample format 's32' for codec 'flac', auto-selecting format 's16'`

I also used sox but i had no warning so i don't know if the conversion was lossless or not.

Also i don't really understand the difference between sample_format and bits_per_sample in my ffprobe output :

`"streams": [
    {
        "index": 0,
        "codec_name": "pcm_s24le",
        "codec_long_name": "PCM signed 24-bit little-endian",
        "codec_type": "audio",
        "codec_time_base": "1/48000",
        "codec_tag_string": "[1][0][0][0]",
        "codec_tag": "0x0001",
        "sample_fmt": "s32",
        "sample_rate": "48000",
        "channels": 1,
        "bits_per_sample": 24,
        "r_frame_rate": "0/0",
        "avg_frame_rate": "0/0",
        "time_base": "1/48000",
        "duration": "0.810667",
        "bit_rate": "1152000"
    }
]`

Comment: The [FLAC format is able to provide a representation for your sample](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FLAC). It's just a question of finding the right tool. Have you considered VLC?

Comment: No i didn't considered VLC, can i do the same thing with it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realised I was using an old version of ffmpeg.

I tested with a more recent one and it worked fine.

Comment: That comment adds a lot more questions.

Comment: @FleetCommand How so? That's what solved the OP's problem; there was some bug or unsupported feature in an old version.

Comment: @slhck This answer is written by the OP! Hence, I imagine there is nothing unclear to him.

Comment: @FleetCommand You said “That comment adds a lot more questions” – I don't understand how. This is not a comment; it's a post in which the OP is answering their own question.

Answer (score 0):

Your PCM is 24-bit samples in a 32-bit store, but the WAV doesn't seem to have flagged that correctly.

Try these two steps:

```
ffmpeg -i KEEP_01.wav -c copy out.wav

ffmpeg -i out.wav output.flac
```

FFmpeg's FLAC encoder only encodes to 16 or 24-bit sample formats. The latter is stored as 32-bit, just like your input.

Comment: Same warning with this additional option. Do you think my original wav file is badly encoded ?

Comment: Try edited cmds.

Comment: Same warning =P

Comment: Upload a small portion of the WAV.

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/g0tqm8estxk55nm/in.wav?dl=1

Comment: Converts fine with your original command. Did a MD5 compare on the decoded FLAC with the PCM. https://www.datafilehost.com/d/65c6855f  Upgrade your ffmpeg.

Comment: Using a more recent version of ffmpeg did the trick. I was trusting our IT department and using a ffmpeg build from 2012 that was in a folder called "ffmpeg-latest". Anyway, thanks !

Comment: Should i delete my post or tag it as resolved since the issue isn't really relevant ?

Comment: Keep it. May help others encountering the same error.

Comment: @Narthe You should answer your own question by clicking the button below. Also, next time, please include the full, uncut command line output in your question, so troubleshooting becomes easier for others.